# Java DB checking against Date/Time fields (event handling)?

Tags: java, javadb

How can I come up with a mechanism in java where I could monitor the date/time fields inside a Java DB table and as soon as the the date/time fields for one or many of the records match the system time I could grab them for further processing??!  Sample code would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Make date/time field in DB as Timestamp. Then get the value of this field from database. And convert the current time in millisecond and then compare.

```
java.util.Date utilDate=new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Timestamp timest=new Timestamp(utilDate.getTime());

timest.compareTo(timest2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can surely use triggers - those are DB procedures that get executed by DBMS automatically, when a particular event arises, and one such event could be the change of the value of yours date/time fields.

Those procedires are implemented into DB itself, not into your java code.

[Here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_trigger) is the wikipedia article on DB triggers.